# JOB name is a variable

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, job-scheduling

I used to use this instruction for my job name

```
job_name=>' "TR_DB"."myJOB_name" '
```

but now I need to pass the job name as a variable in apex, how to do this ?
I tried this but didn't work

```
job_name=>' "TR_DB".|| :P_12_TESt '
```

Comment: It's because this is a string: `' anything between single quotes '` so to concatenate something you need to `' end one string with a quote ' || ' and start another string with another quote '`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked

```
name => '"TR_DB"."' || :P12_NAME ||'"'
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: @jenzz this is the complete answer to the question !